# Dynamic 'alter session' failing in a PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to alter the session in a PL/SQL block via dynamic SQL, but it is failing. I am using the following script:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=READ COMMITED;';
UPDATE Test."column" SET "columnName" = 5 WHERE "columnType" = 606;
end
```

The error I am getting is:

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, does Oracle prevent altering of sessions after using the begin statement?

Comment: ['committed' has got two 't's](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2015.htm#SQLRF53047). You probably also want to remove the semicolon from the end of the dynamic statement.

Comment: I tried it, and I get the following:ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return

Comment: Wrong one; I meant the semicolon *inside* the dynamic statement, as that usually leads to an ORA-00911 error: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=READ COMMITTED';`

Comment: Thanks! It works! would mark your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed one of the Ts from `COMMITTED`, and you'll usually get an ORA-00911 invalid character error if you have a semicolon inside the dynamic statement you're trying to execute.

It should be:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=READ COMMITTED';
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can help me on how to add this to Entity Framework code first migrations? as in adding it to the Up() method using: Sql("ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=READ COMMITED"); it looks like EF is not able to translate what I have.

Comment: @TechNerd - sorry, no idea, never used EF. But check it doesn't have a native way to set the isolation level; and whether it can run your entire anonymous block in a `sql()` call maybe, as a bit of a hack.

Comment: You're still missing a 'T' in your `Sql()` expression in the comment above.

Comment: @TechNerd - pinging you to make sure you saw William's comment about still missing the T.